# Removing a list of objects from another list

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I've been looking for something like that for days. I'm trying to remove all the elements from a bigger list A according to a list B.

Suppose that I got a general list with 100 elements with differents IDS and I get another list with specific elements with just 10 records. I need remove all the elements from the first list that doesn't exists inside the second list.

I'll try to show the code that I actually don't know how it didnt works.

```
List<Obj> listA = new List<Obj>(); 
List<Obj> listB = new List<Obj>(); 

//here I load my first list with many elements
//here I load my second list with some specific elements

listA.RemoveAll(x => !listB.Contains(x));
```

I don't know why but it's not working. If I try this example with a `List<int>` type, it works nicely but I'd like to do that with my object. This object got an ID but I don't know how to use this ID inside the LINQ sentence.

Comment: The problem is the Contains since both lists does not contains the same object (may be another instance of the same class, but with the same data).

Comment: did you override Equals/GetHashcode on your Obj type to use the ID field instead of the method inherited from System.Object?

Comment: My objects got the same type but different content, just had to compare the IDs and no the whole object. Just followed IAbstract~ answer and worked like a charm... Thanks, guys !

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to compare the IDs:

```
listA.RemoveAll(x => !listB.Any(y => y.ID == x.ID));
```

[List(T).RemoveAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Worked like a charm !! Thanks everyone for the help !

Comment: what is namespace for RemoveAll extension method ? I don't have it .

Comment: Arash, it is part of List. I would bet you may need to call .ToList() on your IEnumerable

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can use the **Except** Extension to do this.

```
var result = listA.Except(listB)
```

Reference: http://www.dotnetperls.com/except

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove a list of objects (`listB`) from another list (`listA`) use:

```
listA = listA.Except(listB).ToList()
```

Remember to use ToList() to convert `IEnumerable<Obj>` to `List<Obj>`.

Answer (score 1):

who ever is viewing this now.I think `var result = listA.Intersect(listB)` will give the result for common values in the both the list.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation on MSDN ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx ), contains uses the default Equality comparer to determine equality, so you could use IEquatable's Equals method on your Obj class to make it work. HiperiX mentions the ref comparison above.

How to add the IEquateable interface: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190.aspx